# MySQL Query unique field but only when there is no double entry

Tags: sql, mysql

Hi im not a native speaker and im not into sql language. I can do some standard queries like select * from table... update and so on but have no expierience in deeper sql questions.

| plz | ort | gemeinde |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | uttenthal | buchkirchen |
| 1000 | buchkirchen | buchkirchen |
| 2000 | mistelbach | buchkirchen |
| 2000 | unterholz | buchkirchen |

I have a table like this and need to get a list of plz where ort <> gemeinde but only when there is no case where ort=gemeinde for this plz.

In this example i only should get plz 2000 because there exists a entry where ort buchkirchen = gemeinde buchkirchen for plz 1000.

Comment: Provide sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO and desired output for this data according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3. The data must include all possible combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Not Exists`

```
select plz from table t1 
where not exists
(select 1 from table t2 where t1.plz = t2.plz and ort = gemenide)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
  SELECT plz
    FROM table
    GROUP BY plz
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ort = gemeinde THEN 1 END) = 0
       AND COUNT(CASE WHEN ort <> gemeinde THEN 1 END) > 0;
```